# How to sum the values in specific rows of Pandas DataFrame into one row?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I am working on a chat analyzer, and trying to make a pie chart for most active users. Suppose I have the following data.

| Name | Number of messages |
| --- | --- |
| A | 234 |
| B | 128 |
| C | 112 |
| D | 97 |
| E | 86 |
| F | 43 |
| G | 32 |
| H | 24 |
| I | 22 |
| J | 9 |

I want to convert it into the following

| Name | Number of messages |
| --- | --- |
| A | 234 |
| B | 128 |
| C | 112 |
| D | 97 |
| E | 86 |
| Other | 130 |

I am using *pandas.value_counts()* method for getting all the data for the first table, but am not able to use *pandas.group_by()* to get the second table.

Please can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `df.where` to convert names outside of a defined list to `Other`:

```py
# If name is A, B, C, D or E, keep it. Otherwise, change it to Other
name = df["Name"].where(df["Name"].isin(["A", "B", "C", "D" ,"E"]), "Other")

df.groupby(name)["Number of messages"].sum()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
# Find rows that have Name==["A", "B", "C", "D" ,"E"]
m = df["Name"].isin(["A", "B", "C", "D" ,"E"])

# Get rows that have Not Name == ["A", "B", "C", "D" ,"E"]
df_tmp = df[~m]

# Drop rows that have indexes like df_tmp from original 'df'
# Append row with Name=='Other' and sum 'Number of messages' from 'df_tmp'
df = df.drop(df_tmp.index
            ).append({'Name' : 'Other', 
                      'Number of messages': df_tmp['Number of messages'].sum()
                     }, ignore_index=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Name  Number of messages
0      A                 234
1      B                 128
2      C                 112
3      D                  97
4      E                  86
5  Other                 130
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us try `rank` with `clip`

```
s = df['Number of messages'].rank().clip(5)
out = df.groupby(s).agg({'Name':'first','Number of messages':'sum'}).sort_index(ascending=False).replace({'F':'other'})
Out[295]: 
                     Name  Number of messages
Number of messages                           
10.0                    A                 234
9.0                     B                 128
8.0                     C                 112
7.0                     D                  97
6.0                     E                  86
5.0                 other                 130
```